# Aveo 2012 brakes do not work when the engine is running

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, aveo

I have this problem when you depress the brake pedal it moves all the way to the floor and does not slow the car down. It's happen only when the engine is started.

Please any fix or help.  I really don't have much experience with this kind of thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Obviously the car isn't stopping. Are you pressing on the pedal and it goes to the floor? Or does it just not stop the car like it should? There is no way to even *start* to help you with the lack of information you've given.

Comment: sorry for my english it doesn't stop the car like it should and the Brake pedal is so easy to push

Comment: @AmeerFakhri -  Please add as much information into your question as possible.  someone will be able to help you if you provide the data points.  The delta between what your car used to drive like and how does not would be very helpful.

Comment: @Paulster2 I think he is having a brake fluid leakage..

Comment: @AmeerFakhri Are You are meaning that when you depress the brake pedal it move all the way to the floor and does not slow the car down ? Does this happen only when your engine is started?

Comment: @Anarach Yes exactly

Comment: Check the brake fluid reservoir and the brake line for any leaks. Reformat the question so that it is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low brake pedal and poor brake performance could be the result of any one of the following:
  Air in the brake lines;
  Low brake fluid level;
  A leak in the brake lines or slave cylinders;
  Defective master cylinder.

The reason it is more pronounced when the engine is running is because of the power assist provided by the brake booster, but most likely you would be able to push the pedal to the floor with the engine off too if you used enough force.

Since you stated in your original post that you 'don't have much experience with this kind of thing' I strongly suggest that you seek the advice of a professional mechanic or a trusted friend who is very good with cars. A car's braking system is not something you want to take chances with.